# How to align the slider bars on a panel using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-slider

I have a [control panel](https://jsfiddle.net/7paadw64/8/) with 6 slider bars on it (implemented by bootstrap-slider), but those 6 slider bars seem to align differently with different window size: sometimes 4+2 and sometimes 2+2+2. I have no idea what a good-looking control panel is but I think mine is not elegant. I do not want them to drift "randomly", like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRqSe.png), what shall I do?

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="appDiv">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="controlPanel">
      <div id="sliders">
        <!-- Slide bars -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="slider col-sm-4">
            <label for="mySamples" class="slideLables">Samples \( N=2^q \)</label>
            <input id="mySamples" min="2" max="10" value="6" step="1" class="sliderBars">
            <span id="samplesSliderVal" class="sliderVal"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="slider col-sm-4">
            <label for="myPhase" class="slideLables">Phase \( \phi \)</label>
            <input id="myPhase" data-slider-min="-4.99" data-slider-max="4.99" data-slider-value="0" data-slider-step="0.01" class="sliderBars">
            <span id="phaseSliderVal" class="sliderVal"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="slider col-sm-4">
            <label for="b1" class="slideLables">Amplitude \( b_1 \)</label>
            <input id="b1" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="1" data-slider-value="0" data-slider-step="0.01" class="sliderBars">
            <span id="b1SliderVal" class="sliderVal"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="slider col-sm-4">
            <label for="b3" class="slideLables">Amplitude \( b_3 \)</label>
            <input id="b3" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="1" data-slider-value="0" data-slider-step="0.01" class="sliderBars">
            <span id="b3SliderVal" class="sliderVal"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="slider col-sm-4">
            <label for="b5" class="slideLables">Amplitude \( b_5 \)</label>
            <input id="b5" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="1" data-slider-value="0" data-slider-step="0.01" class="sliderBars">
            <span id="b5SliderVal" class="sliderVal"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="slider col-sm-4">
            <label for="b7" class="slideLables">Amplitude \( b_7 \)</label>
            <input id="b7" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="1" data-slider-value="0" data-slider-step="0.01" class="sliderBars">
            <span id="b7SliderVal" class="sliderVal"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#appDiv {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(193, 193, 193) 0px, rgb(210, 210, 210) 100%);
  text-align: center;
}

.slider {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.sliderBars {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.sliderVal {
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
var sampleSlider = $('#mySamples').bootstrapSlider({});
var phaseSlider = $('#myPhase').bootstrapSlider({});
var b1Slider = $('#b1').bootstrapSlider();
var b3Slider = $('#b3').bootstrapSlider();
var b5Slider = $('#b5').bootstrapSlider();
var b7Slider = $('#b7').bootstrapSlider();
var nSample = Math.pow(2, sampleSlider.bootstrapSlider('getValue'));
var phase = phaseSlider.bootstrapSlider('getValue');
var b1 = b1Slider.bootstrapSlider('getValue');
var b3 = b3Slider.bootstrapSlider('getValue');
var b5 = b5Slider.bootstrapSlider('getValue');
var b7 = b7Slider.bootstrapSlider('getValue');

// Interactive interfaces
sampleSlider.bootstrapSlider({
  formatter: function(value) {
    return Math.pow(2, value);
  }
});

sampleSlider.on('slideStop', function() {
  nSample = Math.pow(2, sampleSlider.bootstrapSlider('getValue')); // Change "global" value

  $('#samplesSliderVal').text(nSample)
});

phaseSlider.on('slideStop', function() {
  phase = phaseSlider.bootstrapSlider('getValue'); // Change "global" value

  $('#phaseSliderVal').text(phase)
});

b1Slider.on('slideStop', function() {
  b1 = b1Slider.bootstrapSlider('getValue'); // Change "global" value

  $('#b1SliderVal').text(b1)
});

b3Slider.on('slideStop', function() {
  b3 = b3Slider.bootstrapSlider('getValue'); // Change "global" value

  $('#b3SliderVal').text(b3)
});

b5Slider.on('slideStop', function() {
  b5 = b5Slider.bootstrapSlider('getValue'); // Change "global" value

  $('#b5SliderVal').text(b5)
});

b7Slider.on('slideStop', function() {
  b7 = b7Slider.bootstrapSlider('getValue'); // Change "global" value

  $('#b7SliderVal').text(b7)
});

$('#samplesSliderVal').text(nSample);
$('#phaseSliderVal').text(phase);
$('#b1SliderVal').text(b1);
$('#b3SliderVal').text(b3);
$('#b5SliderVal').text(b5);
$('#b7SliderVal').text(b7);
```

## **Edit**

After I use komal's method, I still have other problems like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAeG4.png) figure shows. I do not know why this cannot be reproduced in the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et7pvqpj/38/), but it is really a problem. Besides, I also want to fix the positions of the texts in class `sliderVal`, i.e., they appear in the same line where the slider bars appear, rather than shown at another line when the window shrinks, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfJMl.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `class slider` from divs and also remove second `div class= row`. here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/et7pvqpj/37/

Comment: It works to some extent, but I still have a little problem when running in my browser, I have edited the question.

Comment: how do you want to fix the positions of the texts in class sliderVal.

Comment: also have you exported all the libraries mentioned in jsfiddle in your project

Comment: Sorry, I did not make it clear, I have added some details.

Comment: Yes, I exported all the libraries mentioned in jsfiddle in my project.

Comment: here is the updated fiddle  regarding position of slider val http://jsfiddle.net/et7pvqpj/40/